# React app error Object doesn't support property or method 'closest'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, polyfills, core-js

I'm trying to run my react app (using Material-UI) on IE 11. Some of my functionality doesn't work and i'm having this error in my browser:
[image]

I tried this:
`import 'core-js/stable'`
and this:
`import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11' import 'react-app-polyfill/stable'`
but the result is kind of the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material-UI doesn't support  IE 11 in their new component.

Answer (score 0):

If something looks like it should work but it doesn't, a really easy and simple fix could be closing your IDE and reopen it,

if it hasn't fixed I would try to delete the node_modules folder and then `npm install` again